# jquery ajax POST but PHP seeing GET?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm sending some data over with jQuery/Ajax.  My code is marked as POST, but PHP is actually seeing it as GET.  What gives?

```
$.ajax({
         url: url,
         type: "POST",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (results) {
               callback(results);
         },
         error: function (req, msg, obj) {
               console.log('An error occured while executing a request for: ' + url);
               console.log('Error: ' + msg);
         }
});
```

I'm able to confirm it's coming in on the PHP side as GET by doing print_r($_GET) and print_r($_POST)

Comment: This isn't a cross domain request is it?

Comment: check your browser console to see what is actually sent

Comment: No. It's coming from Spotify/local-machine and hitting a remote API

Comment: what data you are try to send?

Comment: form data, user inputting a comment and clicking send

Comment: Do you have active redirects (via `.htaccess` or similar)?

Comment: I don't see any data being sent with the POST, so how can you receive anything in PHP?

Comment: @Steve OP could be sending that as part of the URL, i.e. `/deletepost/2` would be valid.

Comment: ah I was forming my url as http://website.com/api/?var1=data&var2=test... i see what the issue is now

Comment: @Tieson - but those variables would then show up as $_GET in PHP, not $_POST.

Comment: @Tieson - `/deletepost/2` in URL will be interpreted in GET on the PHP server side. Yes it is valid, but No it not POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you r not sending any data in post. try add some data and check in server side.

JS

```
<script>
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data    : {
      'sample' : 'sample_data' 
    },
    success: function (results) {
      callback(results);
    },
    error: function (req, msg, obj) {
      console.log('An error occured while executing a request for: ' + url);
      console.log('Error: ' + msg);
    }
  });
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php

$sample = '';

if (isset($_POST['sample'])) {
  $sample = $_POST['sample'];
}

echo $sample;

?>
```

// Output

```
sample_data
```

Answer (score 0):

I think through the url you are passing values instaed of get if you want to post try like

```
$.ajax({
     url: url,
     type: "POST",
     data:{'my_var':'gautam'},
     -------------
```

and in php you can use like

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);    //or you can print_r($_POST['my_var']);
?>
```

gives you 'gautam'...

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` to check if its `GET` or `POST`

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
```

Answer (score -1):

Use $_REQUEST[] for getting both POST and GET method values

```
<?php
  print_r($_REQUEST);
  extract($_REQUEST);
  echo "sample : ".$sample;

?>
```

output: 
     sample : sample_data

Comment: whoever gave this a -1 should explain why, because, by definition, REQUEST does indeed contain contents of both GET and POST (and COOKIE) ... http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php